# How to fix input string error when converting string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, type-conversion, int32

I am marking some code and cannot understand why this error keeps throwing up (Same code works on other pupil solutions. This is a simple add client form. Trying to add the details into a text file. The error "Input string was not in a correct format" keeps showing up when clicking on the button to add.
All help appreciated
The code is shown below:

```
  if (File.Exists("CompetitorDataFile.txt"))
                {
                    string[] arr = 
    File.ReadLines("CompetitorDataFile.txt").ToArray();
                    I = arr.Length;
                    ID = I + 1;
                    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(ID);

                    for (int z = 0; z  < arr.Length; z++)
                    {
                        string[] arr2 = arr[z].Split('~');

                        if (FrmAdd.ID == Convert.ToInt32(arr2[1]))
                        {
                            valid2 = false;
                            MessageBox.Show("Unique ID needed", 
     "Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ID = I;
                    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(ID);

                }
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() will throw that exception if its given a value that cannot be converted to an int - which is what your doing - so you need to look at the input your giving it.

Comment: I can't see that you write anything into a textfile.

Comment: @AlexK. But it is the ID which is generated using the flor loop which is an int

Comment: Whatever is in arr2[1] likely cannot be converted to an integer.  Put your mouse over it during the exception break to see its value.

Answer (score 0):

I have made small changes in your code provided and executed the core region where you have face the error.

Am not sure that how is your input array of string, I assume 
it in both cases,

1 - contains string ***"ba~7U", "m4~ro5"*** - conversion Fail

2- only numerics ***"01XX~78",*** - conversion Passed

( ***"01XX~70000000008",***, it fails through its `int` type but exceeds the limits of `int`)

```
   static void test()
    {
        int ID, I = 0; int SomeValue = 0;
        //if (File.Exists("CompetitorDataFile.txt"))
        //{
        string[] arr = new string[] { "01XX~78", "ba~7U", "m4~ro5" };
        I = arr.Length;
        ID = I + 1;
        var ss = Convert.ToString(ID);
        int val=0;
        for (int z = 0; z < arr.Length; z++)
        {
            string[] arr2 = arr[z].Split('~');

            if (SomeValue == checkConvertion(arr2[1] ))
            {
              var  valid2 = false;
            }
        }
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ID = I;
        //    var res = Convert.ToString(ID);

        //}
    }

   static  int checkConvertion(string stringInput)
    {
        int val;
        var convertionResult = int .TryParse(stringInput, out val);
        // int.Parse(stringInput);  -- also you can use this
        return convertionResult ? val : 0;
    }
```

You should be more careful to the range of `int` datatype if it exceeds the `int. Max`

(sorry for editing your code, bad naming convetions and commenting lots of areas, I just care to show you the conversion side)